# Counting number of possible combination to reach a sum with a die

Tags: algorithm

Assume you need n steps (e.g. 100) to visit back to the start point on Monopoly,
how many combination of rolling a die to reach start point again.

The min throw count is round up (n/6), max is n (throwing 1 for n times).

n might be greater than 10000. But I can't think of any better solution other than brute force.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends if the order matters or not.

Let's say it doesn't. That is,
throwing 1, 2, 3 is the same as throwing 3, 2, 1. In this case this Scala snippet should work just fine.

```
  def count(n: Int): Int = {
    def count(n: Int, dots: List[Int]): Int = dots match {
      case _ if n == 0 => 1
      case h :: t if n > 0 => count (n - h, h :: t) + count (n, t)
      case _ => 0
    }
    count(n, List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
  }
```

If the order matters than this would be the solution.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class HexabonacciSolver {

    public BigInteger solve(int n) {
        LinkedList<BigInteger> lastSix = new LinkedList<>();
        lastSix.add(new BigInteger("1"));
        lastSix.add(new BigInteger("2"));
        lastSix.add(new BigInteger("4"));
        lastSix.add(new BigInteger("8"));
        lastSix.add(new BigInteger("16"));
        lastSix.add(new BigInteger("32"));
        if (n < 7)
            return lastSix.get(n - 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 6; i++){
            lastSix.add(lastSix.get(0).add(lastSix.get(1).add(lastSix.get(2).add(lastSix.get(3).add(lastSix.get(4).add(lastSix.get(5)))))));
            lastSix.removeFirst();
        }
        return lastSix.get(5);
    }

}
```

**Explanation: How does it work?**

Let's say you want to know how many different sequences of dice rolls there are to get into the field 100 in Monopoly. You know that to get there the previous rolls had to be either 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 or 1. If you only had the number of different sequences of rolls needed to arrive to the fields 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99 you could just sum them up and get the solution for the field 100. This is exactly what the program does. This is very analogous to how the Fibonacci sequence is build with the difference that the next number in the sequence is calculated by summing up 6 previous numbers (hence the name "Hexabonacci")

The solution is linear `O(N)` in time and constant O(C) in space as we only need to store 6 last numbers of the *Hexabonacci* sequence. 
Since the result for n=10000 has hundreds of digits the Java solution returns a BigInteger.

Let me know if you'd like to see a solution in Scala/Python/JavaScript.

Comment: The order matters. Throwing 1,2 is not the same as 2, 1

Comment: Could you elaborate on the solution when order does not matter? I'm trying to understand where does it come from.

Comment: Hey graffic. I'll assume you do know Scala. Also, assume that we want to count possibilities of travelling through 10 fields in a game. Let's  analyze all `case`s by the level of their difficulty (in my subjective point of view). **1**. The first `case` is entered when a recursion gets to the last stage, for example we already rolled `1`, `2` and `3` and now, if we roll `4` we should add it as a valid way of travelling 10 fields. **2**. The third `case` is similar to the first one.

Comment: Again let's say we rolled `1`, `2` and `3`. In this case if we roll for example `5` (`6` would also do) then we won't achieve a valid travel (`1 + 2 + 3 + 5 > 10`), thus we return 0. **3**. The second `case` is where the magic of a tree bifurcation happens. Once we rolled 1 we have to decide if we want to throw it again, or to exclude it from the future considerations (we might assume this because the order does not matter, that is: if we consider `1, 4, 5` to be the same as `4, 5, 1`, then why not force the algorithm to throw smaller dice first?).

Answer (score 4):

Simple dynamic programming can solve this problem

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int n;
int dp[100010] = {0};
int main() {
    cin >> n;
    dp[0] = dp[1] = 1;
    for(int i=2; i<=n ; i++){
        for(int j=1; j<=6; j++)
            if(i - j >= 0)
                dp[i] += dp[i-j];
    }
    cout << dp[n] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Define `dp[x]` be the total # of the ordered combination to achieve sum `x`, using 1 to 6 each step,

then `dp[x] = sum (dp[x - i]) where  1 <= i <= 6 and x-i >= 0`

The base case is `dp[0] = dp[1] = 1`

One point to note is that the number is growing fast, you may need to use long long / 64bit integer to store the result

---

For example, to achieve 4 steps in total,

dp(4) = dp(3) + dp(2) + dp(1) + dp(0)

= 4 + 2 + 1 + 1

= 8

Corresponding to [1,2,1], [2,1,1], [1,1,1,1], [3,1], [2,2], [1,1,2], [1,3], [4]

Comment: Why did you explicitly make dp[1] part of the base case? Wouldn't it work with dp[0]=1 (starting with int i=1)?

Comment: Sure , just writing the code without thinking too much :p   i dont think it is a big difference though :)